# How to get rid of everything inside <> brackets in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text that looks like

`<00:02:00.820><c> ему</c><00:02:00.970><c> кто</c></c><c.colorE5E5E5><00:02:01.180><c> пойдет</c></c>`

I need to get rid of everything that is inside the `<>` tags, so the result looks like:

`ему кто пойдёт`

How would I do that using Javascript? Would regex like this work:

`string.replace([<^\>]*],'');`

Comment: almost, `/<[^>]*>/g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass either a string or a regular expression literal into `.replace`'s first argument; `.replace([<^\>]*],` isn't valid syntax. I'd prefer to lazy-repeat any character until getting to another `>`, with `<.*?>`:

```js
const str = '<00:02:00.820><c> ему</c><00:02:00.970><c> кто</c></c><c.colorE5E5E5><00:02:01.180><c> пойдет</c></c>';
console.log(
  str.replace(/<.*?>/g, '')
);
```